# current-cat class on single posts

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, wp-list-categories

I'm trying to get the default WordPress categories widget to add the current-cat class on single posts as it does on category archive pages.

I've tried adding the following code from the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744615/add-current-cat-class-on-wp-list-categories-when-im-on-single-with-custom-taxon) to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'sgr_show_current_cat_on_single', 10, 2 );
function sgr_show_current_cat_on_single( $output, $args ) {
    if ( is_single() ) :
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $args['taxonomy'] );
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#cat-item-' . $term ->term_id . '#', $output ) ) {
                $output = str_replace('cat-item-'.$term ->term_id, 'cat-item-'.$term ->term_id . ' current-cat', $output);
            }
        }
    endif;
    return $output;
}
```

But this results in the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are wrong only one parameter is used in this filter, so your function should be like this

```
   function sgr_show_current_cat_on_single($args)
```

For more check here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

Comment: Ah, thanks! That now returns this error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'taxonomy' in functions.php on line 5